# .NET framework 3.5 offline installer asking me to "download and install this feature"

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework, .net-3.5

I am trying to intall .NET framework on a computer that I cannot connect to the Internet

I have downloaded the offline installer from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25150

It is a file called dotnetfx35.exe and it is 237054 kb in size

I need to install this on Windows 10 OS build 19041.388

If I double slick the installer first I need to click "Yes" on the User Account Control dialog box to confirm the installation, but then I get another dialog box with a button that tells me to "Download and install this feature" and it will get the required files from Windows update and complete the installation. I would like to install the required files completely offline. How can I perform an offline installation?

I have seen both

[Installing .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows 8 x64 fails and dism at 65.8% with error code 0x800f081f](https://superuser.com/questions/570902/installing-net-framework-3-5-sp1-on-windows-8-x64-fails-and-dism-at-65-8-with)
[Offline Installer for .NET framework 3.5, still requiring an internet connection](https://superuser.com/questions/1114664/offline-installer-for-net-framework-3-5-still-requiring-an-internet-connection)

I have used a windows 10 ISO and tried the DISM method. Dism command says enabling features 100% but then spews out an error 0x800f081f message. Using /Get-Features command with dism says

Feature name: NetFx3
Status: Disabled with Payload removed

for the netfx3 feature.

E:\sources\sxs folder has the following files:

microsoft-windows-internetexplorer-optional-package.cab (290 kb)
Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Optional-Package-en-us.cab (30 kb)
microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package.cab (70697 kb)
Microsoft-Windows-NetFx3-OnDemand-package-en-us.cab (112 kb)

How do I get this .Net 3.5 thing to install?

Comment: .NET Framework 3.5 cannot (impossible) be installed with the offline installer, it’s incompatible, with Windows 8.1, Windows 10, and Windows 11. The only two ways to install it is through the GUI allowing you to install optional Windows features and using the DISM command.  Since you’re getting an error that suggests WinSXS is corrupted. **You have essentially linked to both questions that are duplicates of this question.** My suggestion is perform an in-place repair and then install the optional feature.